# Android: Unable to get Autosearchresults into listview

Tags: android, android-listview, google-places-api

Hi in my project i want to display places auto search results into listview instead of displaying in autocompletetextview. same as seach in google maps .below is my adapter class

```
class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList,resultListgetride;
    private ArrayList<String> autocomplete;
    Activity reg = new AutoSearchActivity();

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size(); 

    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = ((AutoSearchActivity) reg).autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }  
}
```

I have the listview in a activity and in my activity i have this method

```
ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {


        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&components=country:ind");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }
        System.out.println("places resultList"+resultList.toString());
        return resultList;
    }
```

In Activity onCreate method iam doing as below

```
final ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(AutoSearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But iam getting nullpointer exception. can someone help how to get this search results into listview.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who lands up here later. The code above is ok for showing autocomplete in a `ListView`. The only problem seems to be that the `ListView` wasn't assigned a `View` id and the it did not have filter enabled. The following should do the trick.

```
adapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(AutoSearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```